# Initializing views inside routers

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to experiment with Backbone.js and started by trying to reconfigure one of the standard ToDo tutorials.

This is the todo.js file I started with (not sure where I got it from):

```
$(function(){

    AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $(".content"),

        events: {
            "keypress #new-todo": "createOnEnter",
        },

        createOnEnter: function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
            $("#todo-list").append("<li>"+$("#new-todo").val()+"</li>")
            $("#new-todo").val('');
        }

    });

    App = new AppView;

});
```

I wanted to see if I could figure out how to run everything through a router instead, so I tried this:

```
$(function(){

    AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $(".content"),

        initialize: function(options) {
            this.router = this.options.router;
        },

        events: {
            "keypress #new-todo": "createOnEnter",
        },

        createOnEnter: function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
            var term = $("$new-todo").val()
            $("#todo-list").append("<li>"+term+"</li>")
            $("#new-todo").val('');
            this.router.navigate("stage/"+term);
        },

    });

    // create router
    AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        initialize: function() {
            // create view when router is initialized
            new AppView({router : this});
        },

        routes: {
            "stage/:stage" : "renderStage"
        },

        renderStage: function(stage) {
            alert(stage);
        }

    });


    App = new AppRouter;

});
```

But nothing seems to work.  No events fire from the view, and no routes fire off either.  When I debug in the console, I can access `App` which has the following parameters and methods:

```
_extractParameters
_routeToRegExp
bind
initialize
navigate
route
trigger
unbind
constructor
```

Comment: try starting the history: Backbone.history.start(); after you instantiate the router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems with your code:

- `var term = $("$new-todo").val()` should be `var term = $("#new-todo").val()`
- You need to pass `true` as the 2nd parameter to `router.navigate()` to indicate you wish to trigger the routing.
- As *rkw* pointed out, don't forget to call `Backbone.history.start();` in AppRouter's `.initialize()`

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/onocis/3/edit#javascript,live)** is the working code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write

> this.view = new AppView({router : this});

instead of

> new AppView({router : this});

Because in your code, the AppView instance will be garbage collected just after creation since you hold no reference to it.

Comment: `AppView` cannot get garbage collected, because it is used - e.g. has handlers registered.